# AWS Glue automatic job creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have pyspark script which I can run in AWS GLUE. But everytime I am creating job from UI and copying my code to the job .Is there anyway I can automatically create job from my file in s3 bucket. (I have all the library and glue context which will be used while running )

Comment: What if you use an S3EventNotification when a file lands to trigger a Lambda that then creates a specific Glue job.

Comment: Yes AWS provides both AWS cli command and boto3 client which can create, execute, and delete Glue job dynamically. There is enough documentation available with examples on AWS

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). You can define all AWS resources you want to create (not only Glue jobs) in a template file and then update stack whenever you need from [AWS Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks.html) or [using cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html).

Template for a [Glue job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) would look like this:

```
  MyJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Command:
        Name: glueetl
        ScriptLocation: "s3://aws-glue-scripts//your-script-file.py"
      DefaultArguments:
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-enable"
      ExecutionProperty:
        MaxConcurrentRuns: 2
      MaxRetries: 0
      Name: cf-job1
      Role: !Ref MyJobRole # reference to a Role resource which is not presented here
```

Comment: Great piece of information. I was trying to search CloudFormation template to create multiple GlueJobs at once. i.e. your-script-file1.py and your-script-file2.py. Is it possible through CloudFormation?

Comment: @RaxitSolanki absolutely. Just define another resource of type `AWS::Glue::Job` with different logical name (ie. `MyJob1`)

Comment: Thanks ! That means, every time we create a new GlueJob script, We need to update the CloudFormation Template as well. What would be best practice to integrate GlueJob (Test, Deploy) using CodePipeline / CloudFormation? Suppose if I created a new GlueJob script and edited one existing GlueJob (a.py and b.py) in my GitRepo. now, I want to deploy only newly created/edited job (i.e. the one which are edited/created in previous commit). I am currently using CloudFormation, "Git-source" -> CodeBuild Tests and save the artifacts in S3 Bucket. But I am unclear on how would I deploy (multiple Jobs).

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk Which one is the logical name here ? The 'Name' inside Properties, or the 'Name' inside Command.

Comment: @abhijitcaps neither. It's the name of a resource. In my example, it's the root element called "MyJob"

Answer (score 2):

I created an open source library called `datajob` to deploy and orchestrate glue jobs. You can find it on github https://github.com/vincentclaes/datajob and on pypi

```
pip install datajob
npm install -g aws-cdk@1.87.1
```

you create a file `datajob_stack.py` that describes your glue jobs and how they are orchestrated:

```
from datajob.datajob_stack import DataJobStack
from datajob.glue.glue_job import GlueJob
from datajob.stepfunctions.stepfunctions_workflow import StepfunctionsWorkflow


with DataJobStack(stack_name="data-pipeline-simple") as datajob_stack:

    # here we define 3 glue jobs with a relative path to the source code.
    task1 = GlueJob(
        datajob_stack=datajob_stack,
        name="task1",
        job_path="data_pipeline_simple/task1.py",
    )
    task2 = GlueJob(
        datajob_stack=datajob_stack,
        name="task2",
        job_path="data_pipeline_simple/task2.py",
    )
    task3 = GlueJob(
        datajob_stack=datajob_stack,
        name="task3",
        job_path="data_pipeline_simple/task3.py",
    )

    # we instantiate a step functions workflow and add the sources
    # we want to orchestrate. 
    with StepfunctionsWorkflow(
        datajob_stack=datajob_stack, name="data-pipeline-simple"
    ) as sfn:
        [task1, task2] >> task3
```

To deploy your code to glue execute:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=my-profile    
datajob deploy --config datajob_stack.py
```

any [feedback](https://github.com/vincentclaes/datajob/discussions) is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For instance, you can use boto3 framework for this purpose.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_job

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote script which does following:

1. We have (glue)_dependency.txt file, script gets path of all dependency files and create zip file.
2. It uploads glue file and zip file in S3 by using s3 sync
3. Optionally, if any change in job setting will re-deploy cloudformation template

You may write shell script to do it.