# automate uploading of glue script

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

We are currently using cloud formation to create a glue job (via codebuild and codepipeline). The one thing we are stuck on is how to automate the code that goes into the glue job.

Our current relevant piece of the cloudformation template looks like this:

```
MyJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Command:
        Name: glueetl
        ScriptLocation: "s3://aws-glue-scripts//your-script-file.py"
      DefaultArguments:
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-enable"
      ExecutionProperty:
        MaxConcurrentRuns: 2
      MaxRetries: 0
      Name: cf-job1
      Role: !Ref MyJobRole
```

The problem is is the "ScriptLocation". Looks like it is required to be an S3 location. How can we automate the upload of this. The code is in a .py file in our Git repository and I assume is uploaded to the artifact repository as are of the codebuild process, but how to access it?

Would like to hear how others are doing this. Thanks!

EDIT: I was able to find a similar stack overflow post:[AWS Glue automatic job creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193618/aws-glue-automatic-job-creation) but it the answers really don't give a solution or understand the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

I've written [a tool](https://github.com/alexzhangs/xsh) to handle the upload of stack dependencies, including CloudFormation nested templates and non-inline Lambda functions.

Currently AWS Glue was not handled since I haven't try it in any project yet. But it should be easy to expand to support Glue.

The dependencies were defined in separate config file, and a piece of code within the tool is responsible for the config. Here's the sample config:

Nested CloudFormation templates:

```
# DEPENDS=( <ParameterName>=<NestedTemplate> )
#
# Required: Yes if has nested template, otherwise No
# Default: None
# Syntax:
#   <ParameterName>: The name of template parameter that is referred at the
#                    value of nested template property `TemplateURL`.
#   <NestedTemplate>: A local path or a S3 URL starting with `s3://` or
#                     `https://` pointing to the nested template.
#                     The nested templates at local is going to be uploaded
#                     to S3 Bucket automatically during the deployment.
# Description:
#   Double quote the pairs which contain whitespaces or special characters.
#   Use `#` to comment out.
# ---
# Example:
#   DEPENDS=(
#       NestedTemplateFooURL=/path/to/nested/foo/stack.json
#       NestedTemplateBarURL=/path/to/nested/bar/stack.json
#   )
```

Lambda functions:

```
# LAMBDA=( <S3BucketParameterName>:<S3KeyParameterName>=<LambdaFunction> )
#
# Required: Yes if has None-inline Lambda Function, otherwise No
# Default: None
# Syntax:
#   <S3BucketParameterName>: The name of template parameter that is referred
#                            at the value of Lambda property `Code.S3Bucket`.
#   <S3KeyParameterName>: The name of template parameter that is referred
#                         at the value of Lambda property `Code.S3Key`.
#   <LambdaFunction>: A local path or a S3 URL starting with `s3://` pointing
#                     to the Lambda Function.
#                     The Lambda Functions at local is going to be zipped and
#                     uploaded to S3 Bucket automatically during the deployment.
# Description:
#   Double quote the pairs which contain whitespaces or special characters.
#   Use `#` to comment out.
# ---
# Example:
#   DEPENDS=(
#       S3BucketForLambdaFoo:S3KeyForLambdaFoo=/path/to/LambdaFoo.py
#       S3BucketForLambdaBar:S3KeyForLambdaBar=s3://mybucket/LambdaBar.py
#   )
```

The tools were written in bash and come with 2 parts:

1. [xsh](https://github.com/alexzhangs/xsh): It works as a bash library framework.
2. [xsh-lib/aws](https://github.com/xsh-lib/aws): It's a library of xsh.

The code you may need to expand is located in [xsh-lib/aws/functions/cfn/deploy.sh](https://github.com/xsh-lib/aws/blob/master/functions/cfn/deploy.sh).

The example deploy command looks like:

```
$ xsh aws/cfn/deploy -C /path/to/your/template-and-config-dir -t stack.json -c sample.conf
```

I'm considering to abstract the dependencies such as CloudFormation template, Lambda functions and Glue, into a single interface for both configs and handlers.
This will make it easier to add new dependency handlers to the deployer.